# Can't update graphQL cache after mutation

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-client

I use apollo-client on node js (without React) to store, get and update data. Create the client like the following:

```
const { ApolloClient } = require('apollo-client');
const { InMemoryCache } = require('apollo-cache-inmemory');
const { SchemaLink } = require('apollo-link-schema');

const gqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  addTypename: false,
  ssrMode: true,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
  }),
  link: new SchemaLink({ schema }),
});
```

Make the queries with `graphql-tag` package:

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');

mylicense = gql`
  query Licenses($userId: String!){
    myLicense(userId:$userId) {
      license{
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

getLicense = gql`
  query Licenses($id: ID!){
    license(_id:$id) {
      _id,
      name,
      value
    }
  }
`,

updateLicense = gql`
  mutation updateLicense($id: ID!, $name: String, $value: String){
    updateLicense(_id:$id, name: $name, value: $value) {
      _id,
      name,
      value
    }
  }
`,
```

I call the update like this (yes, I get the data from a REST request, but it isn't important now):

```
const options = {
  mutation: updateLicense, 
  variables,
  // update or refetchQueries tried here
};
return gqlClient.mutate(options)
  .then(result => res.json({ data: result.data.updateLicense }))
  .catch(next);
```

And here we are, somehow I need to make it update the cache with the `variables` values, because the `mylicense` route doesn't returns with the new value.

```
gqlClient.query({ query: mylicense, { userId: 'anything' } })
```

I read tons of [documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-cache-inmemory#normalization), for example the `update` option:

```
const update = (proxy, { data: { updateLicense } }) => {
  const data = proxy.readQuery({
    query: mylicense,
    variables: { userId: req.params.id },
  });
  data.updateLicense.push(updateLicense);
  proxy.writeQuery({ query: license.get, data, variables });
};
```

It drops an error on the proxy.readQuery line: `Can't find field mylicense({"userId":"..."}) on object (ROOT_QUERY)`

Another option is the `refetchQueries`, what should be more simple, and at least doesn't drop an error, but doesn't doing anything:

```
const refetchQueries = [
  { query: mylicense},
  // or
  'myLicense'
  // or 
  { query: mylicense, variables: { userId: variables.id } },
];
```

I tried to make the client with different settings:

```
const gqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  addTypename: false,
  ssrMode: true,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    dataIdFromObject: ({ id }) => id || null,
    addTypename: false,
  }),
  dataIdFromObject: ({ id }) => id || null,
  link: new SchemaLink({ schema }),
});
```

Still nothing.

I really out all of my ideas. As I see, graphQL mainly used on React, maybe my problem is node js specific, I don't know...

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: With `refetchQueries` you only need to add name of your query in that like `const refetchQueries = ["Licenses"];`

Comment: And in your `update` function, be sure that `variables` of `mylicense` is the same with the one you use in your query

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy the 'myLicense' is the name of the query, one of the way, how I tried it was that. And yes, the variables are the same like in the query.

Comment: Can you show your `proxy` in your `update`? It can be help us to figure what error occur here.

Comment: And my fault it isn't your name of query, it is name in `gql` tag like `Licenses` or `updateLicense` above

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The proxy has a lot of content, what do you want to see?

Comment: Check `ROOT_QUERY` in your cache https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVCCL.png